# How to pass a Parcelable class which contains a list of another parcelable class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I'm trying to pass a Parcelable class from one Activity to another. I do it like this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(ClosedChatActivity.this, AdminProfileActivity.class);intent.putExtra("adminProfile", adminProfile);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then get it in the other Activity like this:

```java
adminProfile = (AdminProfile) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("adminProfile");
```

This is the AdminProfile class and the WebLink class it has inside:

```java
public class AdminProfile implements Parcelable {
    public static final Creator<AdminProfile> CREATOR = new Creator<AdminProfile>() {
        @Override
        public AdminProfile createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new AdminProfile(in);
        }

        @Override
        public AdminProfile[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AdminProfile[size];
        }
    };
    public Long idUser;
    public String name;
    public String professio;
    public String description;
    public List<WebLink> webLinks;
    public Long idOficina;

    protected AdminProfile(Parcel in) {
        idUser = in.readLong();
        name = in.readString();
        professio = in.readString();
        description = in.readString();
        webLinks = in.createTypedArrayList(WebLink.CREATOR);

        idOficina = in.readLong();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeLong(idUser);
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(professio);
        parcel.writeString(description);
        parcel.writeLong(idOficina);
        parcel.writeTypedList(webLinks);
    }
}
```

```java
public class WebLink implements Parcelable {
    public static final Creator<WebLink> CREATOR = new Creator<WebLink>() {
        @Override
        public WebLink createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new WebLink(in);
        }

        @Override
        public WebLink[] newArray(int size) {
            return new WebLink[size];
        }
    };
    public String name;
    public String url;

    protected WebLink(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        url = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        WebLink webLink = (WebLink) obj;
        assert webLink != null;
        return this.name.equals(webLink.name) && this.url.equals(webLink.url);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(url);
    }
}
```

When I get the object, the two Strings in it aren't the same I sent. Why is that?

The weird thing is that I have another Parcelable class which contains an AdminProfile, and when sending that class it does send fine with the Weblinks included, but if I send only an AdminProfile somewhere in the way it fails.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for problems/questions about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

When you read and write `Parcelable` classes, you need to make sure that the order of the elements is exactly the same.

You are writing `idOficina` followed by `WebLinks`, but you are reading them in the opposite order.